# phpDocumentor document a variable accesable from every part of code Zend2

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, documentation, phpdoc

Hello i have a bootloader where i define some basis services  like

```
/** @var $serviceManager Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager */
$serviceManager = new ServiceManagerComposite(new ConfigurationComposite($configuration['service_manager']));
```

But this type of documentation is not available trough my legacy code for hinting, as i found out this will define the variable only on tht one php file. But because i use it as a legacy acess point for my code i need it for the whole php project...

Any sugestions what type of documentation would work with the IDE hinting from Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to duplicate at least the first use of `$serviceManager` with the same `@var` docblock in each file.  If NetBeans is not already resolving scope for you via requires and includes, then this would be the only way to put a context on that "local" variable in the file you're in.

Comment: Ye tht is the solution i went with. interestingly nb dous not recognise /** anotation outside of class variables. you have to use /* anotation to make it work. And i cant bring NB to parse my bootstrap so i get intelsense from it ~_~

Answer (score 0):

Sangoku is perfectly right!

/* @var $serviceManager Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager */

Should do the trick